# How to Update android app by programmatically without android market

Tags: android, google-play

I need some help,

1) I am developing app in which I want to display offline web site including videos so i added videos in raw folder for offline access of app and i want to change that videos after some days( may be add or delete some videos from app).
so is it possible to update my app without using android market?

The idea is when i start app it will parse json and check wether new version of app is available on my site or not. If it is available than it will start download of it(i don't want to open browser for download. update should be done within my app or in background ) and reinstall it .How can i do that by programmatically?

also how can i cache the entire website in web view.currently i am using this code but it cache only visited pages (the page that we open in app)

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
 webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*24);
 String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
 webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
 webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
 webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
 if(isNetworkAvailable() == true){
 webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.xyz.com");
  } else {
 webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.xyz.com");
  }   } }
```

2)How can i install apk from mac to tablet by usb without clicking on run button of eclipse.
I want to install this apk to 200 tablets, so i am looking for some batch program or some script which will be one click install script for app.
I search on gooogle i found one [Multiple apk on click](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=970348) but i don't know that it will work on Non rooted tablet or not.

Waiting for reply.
Thank you

Comment: I have an open source project that allows you to check for, download and install updates from within your app [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker/)

Comment: @RaghavSood Thank you so much man..do you have some implementation sample? and after download the apk it will ask user to install?. what happen if same app is running and you complete download than it quit the app and install or wait until quit and than install update.

Comment: There is an integration guide [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker/wiki/API-2-Integration-Guide). Other than that, you can choose to download and install instantly, or download it, and install it at separate times. It will download and install if by quitting your app if it is in the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this 
first use push notifications and tell users that new version when they click on the notification download the apk from your web server and let them install (I have used this one )

other option may polling your web server after some fix time say(one day) and check if the new version is available once it is available push that to notification area that a new version is available when user clicks that it will again repeat the above procedure for this all you need is web server that you will request to send and from where you will make users download the application

Comment: hmmm sounds cool..but when i click on notification that download update than it wont open the web browser download..it should downloaded in my app (OR in background). can you share your sample implementation code with me if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think store videos etc as resources is a bad way.

You can sync you data by timer with your site and store all in db or sd card - so you don't need to reinstall app, but only download some data sometimes and all of the data will be on your device and avaliable offline.

And about script - you can write your own and only run `abd install app` - so you will only need to start your adb without opening IDE.

BTW you can "reinstall" your app without users actions (on non rooted device) - so it's very inconvenient for user to reinstall your app many times.

**UPDATED**

To install app via usb - this person must have adb.

> they don't want to wait until download completes

but in this case they have to wait until app is downloaded =).
They have to download the content even this content in resources or avaliable online.

If you want to create such app with built-in content you can face with some problems:

- Some devices will not accept you very huge APK (>20 mb for htc desire for example is a bad idea =)
- Each time you want to update your app, people have to redownload huge amount of infarmation, if you build-in online caching they can spend much less time to download diff. Even if people install your app via usb - you can put all data on sdcard.
- You can't upgrade your app on non rooted devices in such way that people wouldn't be angry - the'll have to reinstall your app each time. But with my method thay can sleep and content can download.

So i can't imagine any usecase when your method is better than usual "online" methods.

Comment: i want something like batch files (like windows) which will do all work in one click and install ( for non technical person to install app on tablet) or like make files .. but i dont know how can i create it. can you help me.

Comment: i am working on app which is more offline and less online..like when i install app on tablet use will get all information offline. they don't want to wait until download completes.your idea is good but my case is different ,Thats why when new video added i will add it in project folder and make a version update for my app and it will download and update automatically . do you have any other suggestion?